# How to resize a canvas properly in React using p5js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, p5.js

I'm currently working on a project and one part is about resizing the model in the canvas once the canvas is resized (or window is resized). I have checked documentation for [resizeCanvas()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/resizeCanvas) and applied it.

I'm first finding the ratio by dividing the `currentWidth/defaultWidth` which are currentWidth of the user's device and the default/selected width by us, respectively.

```
  findRatio(wd, hd, wc, hc) {
    const w = wc / wd;
    const h = hc / hd;
    return w < h ? w : h;
  }
```

and in my `windowResized()` function, I'm setting width/height once canvas is resized on window resize.

```
export const windowResized = (p5) => {
  if (p5) {
    initVariables.browserWidth = p5.windowWidth;
    initVariables.browserHeight = p5.windowHeight;
    p5.resizeCanvas(initVariables.browserWidth, initVariables.browserHeight);
    for (let m of initVariables.mM) {
      m.updateonResize();
    }
  }
};
```

here initVariables is just an object with some bunch of variables.

I also have `updateonResize()` function in my parent class that triggers once window is resized.

```
 updateonResize() {
    this.r = this.findRatio(
      this.initVariables.width,
      this.initVariables.height,
      this.initVariables.browserWidth,
      this.initVariables.browserHeight
    );
    this.arr.push(this.r);

    if (this.arr[this.arr.length - 2] !== undefined) {
      if (this.r < this.arr[this.arr.length - 2]) {
        console.log("canvas getting larger, not sure if I need to divide or multiply here");
        this.min = this.min * this.r;
        this.max = this.max * this.r;
        this.measure = this.measure * this.r;
      } else {
        this.min = this.min * this.r;
        this.max = this.max * this.r;
        this.measure = this.measure * this.r;
      }
    }
  }
```

Here, `min`, `max`, and `measure` variables are variables to detect the size of object parts which are the length of lines. If the canvas is getting smaller, you need to **multiply measure** value with `ratio` (where ratio is usually less than 1).

**Problem1:**
I'm having a problem when I go to window mode from full-screen mode in my Chrome browser. It does not trigger the `windowOnResize()` function. Is it possible to automatically trigger this function once you go to window mode?

**Problem2:**
When you resize the browser, the ratio changes every frame, and thus `measure*ratio` value becomes too low (to 0). Is there any algorithm I could apply to decrease the measure value slightly, but not drastically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself. I have added resize event listener with JavaScript and find the ratio with my own function and resize the canvas with it. I have added timeout not to see changes at the same time, but after some delay.

```
let timeOutFunctionId;

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
  if (!initVariables.subSet) {
    r = findRatio(
      initVariables.width,
      initVariables.height,
      initVariables.browserWidth,
      initVariables.browserHeight
    );
    clearTimeout(timeOutFunctionId);
    timeOutFunctionId = setTimeout(() => {
      if (p5) {
        if (true) {
          initVariables.browserWidth = p5.windowWidth - 310;
          initVariables.browserHeight = p5.windowHeight - 200;
        } else {
        }
        p5.resizeCanvas(
          initVariables.browserWidth,
          initVariables.browserHeight
        );
        //calling custom class 
      }
    }, 500);
  }
});
```